# Using String.split() How can I split a string based on a regular expression excluding a certain string

Tags: java, regex, split

I have this string:

```
"round((TOTAL_QTY * 100) / SUM(ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY) , 1)"
```

I tried to split the string using the following code:

```
String[] tokens = function.split("[ )(*+-/^!@#%&]");
```

Result is the following array:

```
"round"
""
"TOTAL_QTY"
""
""
"100"
""
""
""
"SUM"
"ORDER_ITEMS"
"->TOTAL_QTY"
""
""
""
"1"
```

But I need to split the string as follows:

```
"round",
"TOTAL_QTY",
"100",
"SUM",
"ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY",
"1"
```

To make it clearer. First of all I need to ignore `->` when it splits the string and then remove those empty strings in the result array.

Comment: You state you "need to ignore `->`", and yet your desired result contains `->`.

Comment: You're using entirely the wrong tool for the job. This task requires a scanner and a parser.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for your comment I revised the question to clarify what I was meant to say

Comment: Probably you  need `.split("(?:[\\s()*+/^!@#%&,]|-(?!>))+")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

Ok, I think you can do it in two steps, replace all non necessary characters with space for example and then split with space, your regex can look like like :

```
[)(*+/^!@#%&,]|\\b-\\b
```

Your code :

```
String[] tokens = function.replaceAll("[)(*+/^!@#%&,]|\\b-\\b", " ").split("\\s+");
```

Note that I used `\\b-\\b` to replace only `-` :

### Solution 2

Or If you want something clean, you can use Pattern with Matcher like this :

```
Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+->\\w+\\b|\\b\\w+\\b")
        .matcher("round((TOTAL_QTY * 100) / SUM(ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY) , 1)")
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\"", s)));
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/QS8z1F/1)

Details

- `\b\w+->\w+\b` to match that special case of `ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY`
- `|` or
- `\b\w+\b` any other word with word boundaries

Note, this solution work from Java9+, but you can use a simple Pattern and Matcher solution.

**Outputs**

```
"round"
"TOTAL_QTY"
"100"
"SUM"
"ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY"
"1"
```

Comment: clever idea to replace special characters with space and straight away split by space.

Comment: Thank you @Govinda Sakhare, I would strongly suggest the second solution instead

Comment: any Idea about the DV please

Answer (score 2):

Could see a couple of very good solutions provide by **YCF_L**

Here is one more solution:

```
String[] tokens = function.replace(")","").split("\\(+|\\*|/|,");
```

Explanation:

`\\(+` Will split by `(` and `+` will ensure that multiple open bracket cases and handled e.g. `round((`

`|\\*|/|,` OR split by `*` OR split by `/` OR split by `,`

Output:

```
round
TOTAL_QTY 
100 
SUM
ORDER_ITEMS->TOTAL_QTY 
1
```